# willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not firing iphone UIInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a view inside a tabbarcontroller and navigationcontroller and my 'willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation' method is not firing.

I have set the view to be FirstResponder and also shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation returning YES;

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) 
interfaceOrientation { 
        return YES;

} 
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

[self becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using UITabBarController inside your application then all of UIViewControllers inside UITabBarController should support autorotation. Otherwise you will not receive autorotation callbacks.